# packaging specified as war but after build I am getting a jar file

Tags: java, maven

pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>omoto</groupId>
    <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>omoto</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
    <spring.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.24</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--dependencies -->
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>7.4.Final</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>deploy-driver</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mysql</artifactId>
                            <name>mysql.jar</name>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>deploy-artifact</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Eventhough, I have specified my packaging as war, after build, I am getting a jar file in target folder. But, when I see the folder structure through eclipse, it's mentioned as war, but in terminal ,its is as a jar file.